# firebase.database is not a function . [Version 7.13.2 of firebase]

Tags: javascript, firebase, iot

I'm trying connect  firebase with javascript to read and write from the web, but I could not do it work. I'm using the version 7.13.2 of firebase.

I'm trying read this from firebase:

```
{
  "device" : {
    "5C:CF:7F:06:01:AD" : {
      "accuracy" : "39",
      "lat" : "4.6740861",
      "lng" : "-74.0916290"
    },
    "5C:CF:7F:D0:8F:44" : {
      "accuracy" : "30",
      "lat" : "4.6740022",
      "lng" : "-74.0915909"
    }
  }
}
```

The error detects it here:

`var database = firebase.database();`

This is show in the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start?hl=es-419

I do not know if is to billing topic, because I using free layer of firebase. 
I thank any help.

below I show code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <!--Muestra el contenido de lectura desde firebase-->
<div id="val"></div>
</body>

<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "<APIKEY>",
    authDomain: "example.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://example.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "example",
    storageBucket: "example.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDERID>",
    appId: "<APPID>"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  //Get a refence to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();


  ////////////Opereaciones de lectura y escritura. Obtenido desde la documentación: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?hl=es//////////////////////

  //Operación de escritura o sobreescritura
  function writeDeviceData(mac, lat, lng, acc){
    firebase.database().ref('device/' + mac).set({
        //Las variables que se muestran abajo deben ser iguales a las 
        //Contenidas en realtime firebase
        lat:lat,
        lng: lng,
        acccuracy: acc
    });
  }

//Operación de lectura cuando detecta cambios en los datos de las variables
 var postElement = document.getElementById("val");
 var mac = "/DE:AD:BE:EF:00";

 var updateStarCount = function(element, value){
    element.textContent = value; }


 var starRead = firebase.database().ref('device/' + mac);
 starRead.on('value', function(snapshot){
    updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
 });

 console.log(database);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: In the future DON'T POST YOUR AUTH KEY. And could you post the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss an import, additionally to the core of Firebase

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Look at this page : 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?hl=fr-419#libraries-hosting-urls

Thinks to remove your credentials from the post

```
const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "APIKEY",
        authDomain: "AUTHDOMAIN",
        databaseURL: "TESTURL",
        projectId: "PROJECTID",
        storageBucket: "PROJECTBUCKET",
        messagingSenderId: "ID",
        appId: "APPID",
        measurementId: "MESUREID"
    };
```

Comment: The missing import concerning the firebase-database.js